# What does this python line mean?

Tags: python, syntax

```
abc = [0, ] * datalen;
```

"`datalen`" is an `Integer`.

Then I see referencing like this:

```
abc[-1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A great idea is to read the Python tutorial :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

creates a list with `datalen` references to the object `0`:

```
>>> datalen = 10
>>> print [0,] * datalen
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You don't really need the comma in there:

```
>>> print [0] * datalen
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Worth pointing out is that if it had been a tuple, you *would* need the comma: `(0,) * 5` is `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` while `(0) * 5` is `0`.

Answer (score 5):

As everyone else has said, [0] * n will give you a list of n zeros, and indexing with negative numbers with a[-k] gives k-th element from the end, like:

```
a[-1]
```

gives the last element of the sequence and

```
a[-3]
```

gives the third last element of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what has been said, remember that this behavior is expected when you are copying mutable objects. Classic trap for new python programmers

```
>>> bc = [0,] * 5
>>> bc
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> bc[2]=4
>>> bc
[0, 0, 4, 0, 0]


>>> bb = [{}, ]*5
>>> bb
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
>>> bb[2]["hello"]="hi"
>>> bb
[{'hello': 'hi'}, {'hello': 'hi'}, {'hello': 'hi'}, {'hello': 'hi'}, {'hello': 'hi'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Very interesting, I guess that's because the dictionaries share the same object reference, when copying?

Comment: @KeyboardMonkey: it's because the multiplication operator repeats the reference to the same dictionary. What you see is a list of multiple views of the same dictionary, not different, independent dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

When used in this context, `*` is the "sequence repetition" operator.

```
>>> datalen = 3
>>> abc = [0,] * datalen
[0, 0, 0]
```

In this case, it looks like it's being used as a way to create an array with `datalen` elements, all of which are initialized to zero.

This works for strings too (since they are also sequences):

```
>>> 'String' * 3
'StringStringString'
```

Answer (score 0):

creates a list with datalen number of zeroes

```
>>> datalen=5
>>> abc = [0, ] * datalen
>>> abc
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```